# How To Avoid Burnout

Tags: writers-block

One of the main issues I've had when writing is burnout. I get really invested in a deep story and work on it for months, milking every second. However, the issue with this is, after a few months I always hit burnout. My mind goes completely blank and I've even had to drop stories because I can't think of anything- it's almost like being blocked but worse. This is very frustrating, is there a good way to avoid burnout like this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/53184/what-to-do-when-you-hit-writers-block and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36766/writers-block-help and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38415/how-to-escape-writers-block and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/help-ive-got-writers-block and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/28780/getting-out-of-writers-block.

Comment: @Nai45 Thank you

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Something I’ve tried:

Just take breaks, don’t stress about a difficult scene in your work that you have not the slightest clue how to work out because you will—more often than not—walk into writing scenes that may be—in your mind—beyond the scope of your capacity to write. Don’t stress about it. It’s okay as this is common for all writers. Sometimes it’s best to drop the story the rest of the day and live the life that is separate from your literary endeavors, and ‘be’ there only to return later to this story. Sometimes it’s good to not worry about your own writing and think about the words of others, then return to your story with “new eyes” so to speak.